# Why 'tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter' is so SLOW and STORAGE-CONSUMING in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm going to write to TFRecord file using [this code](https://github.com/dennybritz/chatbot-retrieval/blob/master/scripts/prepare_data.py#L132-L137):

```
  writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_filename)
  print("Creating TFRecords file at {}...".format(output_filename))
  for i, row in enumerate(create_csv_iter(input_filename)):
    x = example_fn(row)
    writer.write(x.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

The problem is that this process is very slow, such that it's not feasible to write a large dataset even in days!
It's just a writer that serialize to disk. Why it's so slow?! Another problem is that the size of the output file is 10 times greater than the original file!

**Do you know any way to speed up the process of TFRecordWriter and compress the result?**

Comment: Did you find out how to improve the IO speed?

Comment: Also still very much interested in this being resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the speed issue, but you can compress after the fact - `TFRecordReader` supports GZIP and ZLIB compression, e.g.

```
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader(
        options=tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions(
            compression_type=tf.python_io.TFRecordCompressionType.ZLIB
        )
    )
    _, tfrecord = reader.read(file_queue)
    # etc.
```

See more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/python_io/TFRecordCompressionType). Decompression takes a bit of time, but you only really notice it at the start if you're using the TF batching system (so a CPU core can be decompressing and filling your queue while the GPU works away, etc.).

Comment: you can directly write to compressed tfrecords using the following, ```tf_record_options = tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions(tf.python_io.TFRecordCompressionType.GZIP)```
```writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_filepath, options=tf_record_options)```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when the dataset I wanted to use was expensive to create and preprocess.

Using TFRecordWriter was incredibly slow, so instead I used the caching option available on Dataset objects.

```
ds.cache('./cache/train.cache').repeat().batch(32).prefetch(1)
```

The files created are about the same size as those created by TFRRecordWriter, but they're created at the sort of speed you'd expect.

Plus, when you relaunch your notebook, for example, if the files are still available, they're used automatically.